# How to custom UITableView contain many rows, each row contain many subrow?

Tags: ios, uitableview

[image]

How to custom UITable like this:UITableView contain many rows, each row contain many subrows. Use add button to add a subrow ?

Comment: To make question clear. You also have sections rite, A section has many rows and each row will have sub rows correct. A row can be added, similarly a subrow can also be added, am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a structure like this

```
[
    {
        "Title": "Section 1",
        "Rows": [
            {
                "Title": "Row 1",
                "Rows": [
                    {
                        "Title": "Sub Row 1", 
                        "Rows":[]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

It's an array of dictionaries. Each section will have an array of rows and each row will have an array of subrows.

[Source Code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35012982/Demo%20Projects/DemoTableView.zip)

Comment: @DungProton I have put a demo source code with my answer. It just shows how you can display such a data. You can workout the code how to add new rows to each section.

Comment: Thank Anupdas, but your source is missed file Nodes.json

Comment: @DungProton I have updated the source. It now fully add new sections and rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use grouped `tableview` for that but it wont give you the full row width for iphone like in your picture.

If you use plain tableview it should give you the full row look but adding that plus button may become difficult.

You need to have a source lets say an array or a dictionary for each section rows

For the image use `cell.imageView.image= yourimage;`

For the arrow use `cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;`

For that (10) you need either use  `cell.accessoryView= yourcustomview`

```
//create multiple section according to your picture it is 2 
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    //return an integer here from a source,variable or just return static int 
    return 2; 
}
//add plus button for each section
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
// Create header view and add label as a subview
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 400, 320, 400)];

    //add a button to open edit
    UIButton *declineButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [declineButton setTag:section];
    declineButton.titleLabel.tag=1;
    [declineButton setFrame:CGRectMake(450,50,70,40)];
    [declineButton setTitle:@"Edit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIImage *declinebuttonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"orangeButton@2x.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 20, 20, 20)];
    [declineButton setBackgroundImage:declinebuttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [declineButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [declineButton addTarget:self action:@selector(declineEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [view addSubview:declineButton];
    return view;
}

- (IBAction)declineEvent:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSInteger row = button.tag;
   NSInteger column = button.titleLabel.tag;
    //NSIndexPath *selectedSection= [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:column inSection:row];
    NSLog(@"Row is %i column is %i",row,column);
    //populate your source array for the section according to your needs here 

}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return yoursourceforthissection;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use custom table view cell that having a table view.

http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Check this hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar project to this on Github.
Basically its a UITableView with expandable sections. 
The following steps made it work for me:

1. `NSMutableDictionary` for the `dataSource`, the dict contains `NSMutableArrays` as values for each row as key.
2. You will have another `NSMutableArray` with the same size as your `NSMutableDictionary`. This `NSMutableArray` contains `BOOL` values, `YES` stands for the section is unfolded and `NO` for a folded section. In my Case, by default all sections are folded.
   3.The number of sections in your tableView is the size of your `NSMutableDictionary`.
3. If your `NSMutableArray` of `Bool` values contains a `YES` at a certain indexpath, the number of rows for this section is the size of the array you retrive as a value for the indexpath from your `NSMutableDictionary`. Otherwise you will have only 1 row for this section.

Example:

```
if ([[boolArray objectAtIndex:section] boolValue]) {
    return [[yourDict valueForKey:yourKeyForIndexPAth] count];
}else{
    return 1;
}
```

Just check it out und feel free to use the code:

[GitHub Link](https://github.com/pmkDev/PKCollapsingTableViewSections)